# Apache2.2:ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, apache, apache2.2

Apache2 error.log:

```
[Thu Dec 17 18:58:33 2015] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Thu Dec 17 18:58:33 2015] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Thu Dec 17 18:58:33 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
ImportError: No module named site
```

My python version:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

Apache2 config:

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/pkgs
```

And I can import site:

```
me@localhost:/opt/pkgs/python/bin$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 21 2015, 20:17:51) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> 
me@localhost:/opt/pkgs/python/bin$ python2.7
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>>
```

how to fix this problem??? Any helop is welcome. Thanks

**UPDATE**

site.py is in /opt/pkgs/python/lib/python2.7
How to set WSGIPythonHome?

**Why "WSGIPythonHome /usr" works for me????**

Comment: I think [this discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/285229/python-django-wsgi-apache-importerror-no-module-named-site) sums it all up: multiple Python versions, mod_wsgi compiled for older Python version than you're using, etc.

Comment: I have no idea how to set WSGIPythonHome. mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+. I think python 2.7.5 or 2.7.3 should be OK?

Comment: @vrs what is site module?

Comment: @BAE Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Why "WSGIPythonHome /usr" works for me???? very likely because (implied) ubuntu has so called system python that lives in /usr/bin/python hence you are hitting the one that is preinstalled not the one you wish to run. To elaborate a bit more I guess you install mod_wsgi to be able to do something with python and web. That mod_wsgi is mainly built to be used with the the built python. Now if you'd like to run another version I guess you need to make to your installation folder. /opt is a bit unusual location for alternative python but hey who says you need to follow the rules ;)

Answer (score 1):

For ones that step on this question (like me) because you are facing a problem with endless:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

in apache's error.log (/var/log/apache2/error.log)

most probably you have `WSGIPythonHome` pointing to some other (presumably) python location. Default setting IS:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr
```

And what people forget to mention is where this supposed to be it is in:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.conf
```

this file usually starts with:

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>

    #This config file is provided to give an overview of the directives,
    #which are only allowed in the 'server config' context.
    #For a detailed description of all avaiable directives please read
    #http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives
```

Somewhere there you put:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr
```

or

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local
```

or (the best option) remove or comment this setting because /usr suppose to be default setting and use built in python.

or

change, mess up or fix what ever you have messed up with wsgi configuration (like I do when I try to make something work or break and do not know enough ;) )